# soundcloud oauth2 redirect weirdness

Tags: ruby, oauth, soundcloud

When the redirect happens I also see the *access_token* as a parameter in the anchor.

I didn't even ask for an access_token just yet because I don't have the *code* or I am missing something?

`http://mycallback.com/code=**some_code**&signed_up=0#access_token=**some_token**&expires_in=21599&scope=%2A`

Comment: the `#` in the url seems suspicious, shouldn't it be an `&`

Comment: Yes, this might be a security issue.

Comment: If this is the callback url well its normal that you have the access token. Normally the callback is made so you can get the token and show the appropriate view to the user knowing that you have the token to get the infos

Comment: I just realized that the *official* 'ruby' gem has hardcoded the 'response_type=code_and_token'. Never mind :)

Comment: You should post  a self answer to your question! If anybody has the same thing they will know! Also since you are using ruby(?) you should tag it in your question!